# How to create fixed overlay <View> React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I want to make the grey box position is fixed, so when I `scrolldown` or `scrollup` the grey box is stay still on it position.

Is it possible to do such thing in React Native ?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<View>
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.continueToPaymentContainer}>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>                
</View>

container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
},
continueToPaymentContainer:{
    width:width,
    height: 100,
    position:'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try below code. You just have to add your view outside the scroll view.

```
<View>
    <ScrollView>
     // Do your stuff
    </ScrollView>

    <View style={styles.continueToPaymentContainer}>
    </View>              
</View>

container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
},
continueToPaymentContainer:{
    width:width,
    height: 100,
    position:'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found it

All I need to do is just put my `grey box` on the outside of `<ScrollView>`

```
<View>
  <ScrollView>
    <Another element>
  </ScrollView>     
  <View style={styles.continueToPaymentContainer}>
  </View>           
</View>
```

I hope this will helps for future search